# MIPS question about using of ($zero) when adding two integers

Tags: mips

```
.data 
    number1: .word 5
    number2: .word 10
.text 
    lw $t0, number1 ($zero)
    lw $t1, number2 ($zero)
```

in above code in MIPS for adding two integers
why do I need to put `($zero)` at the end of each numbers??
what is the use of that ?

Comment: Note that for this code to work (or even build), the `.data` section has to be located somewhere in the first or last 32k of the address space.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html):

> `LW` -- Load word
>
> *Description:*
>
> A word is loaded into a register from the specified address.
>
> *Syntax:*
>
> `lw $t, offset($s)`

So the instruction:

```
lw $t0, number1 ($zero)
```

loads the register `$t0` with data located at address `number1 + $zero == number1 + 0 == number1`.

The `($zero)` is an offset that's part of the instruction

Comment: It's clear (to me). Though, I suggest you add that the offset is useful when `number1` for example is an array of integers.